# HTML - An XML with Predefined CSS

Tags: html, xml

Since HTML and XML are referred as structure of the data the only difference between HTML and XML is, an HTML tag has predefined CSS style in technical point of view. Am i correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.

HTML, for historical reasons, does not conform to XML syntax requirements (unless you're talking about XHTML).  The most obvious example is the `<br>` tag, which does not have a closing tag.  Also, browsers are extremely forgiving in what they accept and will try to do something halfway meaningful even if the HTML is not valid.  This is in stark contrast to XML parsers, which will reject any XML that is not well-formed.

You are correct that browsers implement a default CSS stylesheet, but there are subtle differences between browsers and between different versions of browsers, so many frameworks clear all defaults and re-specify the CSS for every element.